# in joomla plugin onPrepareContent loads multiple time?

Tags: joomla

i made a plugin to load image before section/category/article title. the problem which i face is that if i give markup/regex in category and article content then the section automatically renders it without any markup/regex. Using joomla 1.5

Comment: please paste some code you're using